# WPF Command Binding ListViewItem. Execute command when ListBoxItem clicked

Tags: wpf, binding, command, listviewitem

It works (Command):

```
<Button Command="{Binding LoadMainCommand, Mode=OneTime}">
    <TextBlock Text="Testo" />
</Button>
```

And how to implement this here (Command) -> (ListViewItem)?:

```
<ListView>
    <ListViewItem>
        <StackPanel>
            <Image Source="../img.png">
        </StackPanel>
        <ListViewItem.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip Content="Testo" Style="{StaticResource tt_style}"/>
        </ListViewItem.ToolTip>
    </ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

Comment: When do you expect your command to fire? When the item is selected? You'll need to use an [interaction trigger](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/06/30/handling-events-in-an-mvvm-wpf-application/) to specify the event that you want to handle when there is no `Command` property.

Comment: But how do I make a trigger? To run this command when you click (ListViewItem) the mouse button.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't pay attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute the command when the item is clicked (and not the content) the easiest would be to add an `InputBinding` to the `ListBoxItem`:

```
<ListView>
  <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
              <Border.InputBindings>
                <MouseBinding MouseAction="{x:Static MouseAction.LeftDoubleClick}"
                              Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}, Path=DataContext.SelectPageCommand}"
                              CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}, Path=SelectedItem}" />
              </Border.InputBindings>

              <ContentPresenter />
            </Border>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Alternatively turn the `ListBoxItem` into a `Button`:

```
<ListView>
  <ListViewItem>

    <!-- You may need to adjust binding path -->
    <Button Command="{Binding LoadMainCommand, Mode=OneTime}">
      <StackPanel>
        <Image Source="../img.png">
      </StackPanel>
    </Button>
    <ListViewItem.ToolTip>
      <ToolTip Content="Testo" Style="{StaticResource tt_style}"/>
    </ListViewItem.ToolTip>
  </ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

Alternatively override the `ControlTemplate` by setting the `ListView.ItemContainerStyle`.

```
<ListView>
  <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">

            <!-- You may need to adjust binding path -->
            <Button Command="{Binding LoadMainCommand, Mode=OneTime}"
                    Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
  <ListViewItem>
    <StackPanel>
      <Image Source="../img.png">
    </StackPanel>
    <ListViewItem.ToolTip>
      <ToolTip Content="Testo" Style="{StaticResource tt_style}"/>
    </ListViewItem.ToolTip>
  </ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the first option is more suitable.